# Create Bulk Record using apex

Tags: apex, batch

How I can Create 5000 new Lead record and each Leadname will be different
 like

```
List<Lead> lList = new List<Lead>();
for(Integer i = 0; i<5000; i++){
    Lead l = new Lead(LastName = 'newLead@@' + i, Email = 'Nlead'+ i +'@ab.com', company = 'NLK'+i);
    lList.add(l);
}
insert lList;
```

do i need to create any batch class?

Answer (score 7):

The current DML records processed limit is [10,000](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_gov_limits.htm). So you can insert all 5,000 in one transaction if you want.

For more than 10,000 you can use [an batch job with an iterator](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_batch_interface.htm#apex_batch_iterable).